# What is the best way to augment (rotate) an image dataset?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of images that I would like to augment by rotating. Something like the attached image where the input image is rotated in to 90, 180 and 270 degrees. Is there a scikit-learn or numpy function that does that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
numpy.rot90(data)
```

`n` times to get what you want